# Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on array in ? ¿Cuál es el error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy intentando hacer un buscador simple pero con `PDO` pero me sale el error cuando  coloco una condición de  mostrar el select cuando el registro sea mayor o igual a 1.

**conexión.php**

```
<?php

function Conectar(){
$conn=null;
$host='localhost';
$db='prestamos';
$us='oelo';
$pass='';

try {
$conn= new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $us, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo ":( Error al conectar a la base de datos".$e;
exit;
}
return $conn;
}
?>
```

**buscador.php**

```
<form action="buscador.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<label> 
<input type="text" name="cliente"> </input>
<input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
</label>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cliente'])){

require_once "conexion.php";
require_once "consulta.php";
}
?>
```

**archivo consulta.php**

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

$con=Conectar();

$cliente=$_POST['cliente'];

//selecciona el cambo nombre de la tabla cliente donde  la variable sea 
parecida al campo
$sql="SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nombre LIKE '%$cliente%'";
$consulta=$con->prepare($sql);
$resultado=$consulta->execute();
$filas=$consulta->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

//en esta linea es donde me sale el error
if ($filas->fetchAll()>=1) {
echo "<div class='table-responsive'>      <table id='grid' class='table 
table-hover table-condensed nowrap dt-responsive' cellpadding='0'>
<thead>
<tr class='active'>
<th>Cedula</th>
<th >Nombre</th>
<th>Apellido</th>
<th>Direccion</th>
<th>Telefono</th>
<th>Celular</th>
<th>Correo</th>
<th>Prestamos</th>
<th>Opciones</th>
</tr>
</thead>
";

foreach ($filas as $registros){
echo "<tr>
<td>".$registros->cedula." </td>
<td>".$registros->nombre." </td>
<td>".$registros->apellido." </td>
<td>".$registros->direccion."</td>
<td>".$registros->telefono." </td>
<td>".$registros->celular." </td>
<td>".$registros->correo." </td>
</tr>

";  }

echo "</table>";

}else{
echo "No hemos encontrado ningun registro con el cliente ".$cliente;
}
?>
```

He intentado colocando `rowCount()` y `columnCount()`. Pero igual sale el error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on array in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Cuál es mi error ?

Principalmente está intentando llamar al método  `fetchAll` en el `if` de un `Array` que es lo que retorna el primer `fetchAll` .

Algunas correcciones a su código para su funcionamiento.

- Si emplea `PDO` y deberían `bindear` los valores y/o variables.
- El tipo de código para el `LIKE` es muy común pero no es la forma correcta de hacer esto  , debería tener algo como `LIKE :nombre` para luego este valor bindearlo.
- No hace falta llamar dos veces `fetchAll` para saber el número de filas que devolvió la consulta. Podría validar directamente con los resultados *para saber si hay filas o no*

**Código final** *consulta.php*

```
$cliente=$_POST['cliente'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nombre LIKE  :nombre";
$consulta=$con->prepare($sql);
$consulta->bindValue(':nombre','%'.$cliente. '%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consulta->execute();
$filas=$consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($filas){
    foreach ($filas as $registros){
        ....
    }
}
else
    echo "NO HAY RESULTADOS";
```